# How can I open a UIViewController from the storyboard with a button in another view programmatically?

Tags: view, swift, ios8

I am trying open a view that is in storyboard from code and i don't know how open this. In objective c was

```
 UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] 
 initWithNibName:@"myXib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
 [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myView"];
```

But I don't know how to make this in Swift.

I have my code outlet declaration and I use this:

```
 @IBOutlet var viewAboutUs : UIView = UIView()

 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {

                        self.viewAboutUs.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 260.0)
```

But with this code, my app crash. How can open this view from code??

Comment: I think the question is not complete!!

Comment: I am trying open a view that is in storyboard from code and i don't know how open this. In objective c was UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myXib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myView"]; But I don¡'t know how to make this in Swift. This is my question..

Comment: ok, please update your question as you posted in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let controller1 = UIViewController(nibName: "myXib", bundle: nil);

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let controller2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myView") as UIViewController
```